# is there any way to use the excelJS (javascript library for excel file create and read) in browser

Tags: javascript, excel, progressive-web-apps, export-to-excel, exceljs

I want to know how can i use the excelJS library on the client-side( browser). the documentation says that the browserify files are in the dist/folder but there is not any file in that folder. so how to use this library in the browser.